# memory_relaxed and VarHandler

Tags: c++11, java-memory-model

In https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#myth-barriers-are-sane
the author wrote:

> Of course, without keeping reads in order, the result 1, 0 is
>   trivially achievable. But this does not make an interesting test case.
>   The actual test is clever about that: it uses the new VarHandles
>   "opaque" access mode, which inhibits these optimizations and exposes
>   the reads to hardware in the same order:[3]

and [3]:

> 3. This sounds very similar to C/C++11 std::atomic(…​, memory_order_relaxed), which is what it is modeled after. Very convenient for hardware concurrency testing, as in this example.

I am not sure what the author means because he says that

> which inhibits these optimizations and exposes the **reads to hardware in the same order**

whileas

`memory_order_relaxed` allows every reordering (it doesn't give any special guarantees in memory ordering).

Comment: you are seriously trying to understand things that not so many people are even understanding the question... +1 for the effort.

Comment: `memory_order_relaxed` is so weird that even the C++ committee last I checked recommended against using it because it's not clear how to use it properly.

Comment: memory_order_relaxed will not order loads/stores to different variables, but it will order loads and stores to the same variable: this is called coherence. And opaque provides the same ordering guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct: opaque isn't enough there because it only orders [accesses to the same variable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html).

The same example in JCStress' source code [uses volatile mode instead of opaque](https://github.com/openjdk/jcstress/blob/0.15/jcstress-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jcstress/samples/jmm/advanced/AdvancedJMM_01_SynchronizedBarriers.java#L105).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).